# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I am getting the below error when i trying to run setup upgrade command.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key, query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` MODIFY COLUMN `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL   COMMENT "Entity ID", DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`customer_group_id`,`website_id`), ADD INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`), ADD INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`), ADD INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_TMP_MIN_PRICE` (`min_price`), DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8', DEFAULT COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
```

This is the structure of table **catalog_product_index_price_tmp**

[image]

Please let me know if you have any idea , how to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to modify this table or this is something you receive when you run setup: upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete this `temp` table "`catalog_product_index_price_tmp`".

It will automatically created after run commands.

**Note** : Take database backup before doing operation.